# Why is returning a string faster than returning a static string?

Tags: c++

[Live on Quick C++ Benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/UHk_EGDFjHNZ3aWVVqBR6SND47s)

Question> The function `return_string` returns a `std::string` through a string literal. While the function `return_static_string` returns a pre-allocated `static std::string`. The performance measurement surprised me that the `return_string` is significantly faster than `return_static_string`. Can someone please give me some advices why this happens?

Thank you

```
#include <numeric>

static std::string return_string(int type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
    case 0:
        return "apple";
    case 1:
        return "orange";
    case 2:
        return "banana";
    }
    
    return {};
}

static void default_return_string(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int> v(10000);
    std::iota(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 0);

  for (auto _ : state) {
   for (const auto &n : v) {
        auto ignore = return_string(n % 3);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ignore);
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(default_return_string);

static std::string return_static_string(int type)
{
  static const std::string ap = "apple";
  static const std::string ora = "orange";
  static const std::string ba = "banana";

    switch(type)
    {
    case 0:
        return ap;
    case 1:
        return ora;
    case 2:
        return ba;
    }
    
    return {};
}

static void static_return_string(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int> v(10000);
    std::iota(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 0);

  for (auto _ : state) {
   for (const auto &n : v) {
        auto ignore = return_static_string(n % 3);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ignore);        
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(static_return_string);
```

Updates based on sklott's idea.
Now, the function `return_static_ref_string` runs faster than the function `return_string`. The culprit is that I should NOT use copy-return.

```
static const std::string& return_static_ref_string(int type)
{
  static const std::string ap = "apple";
  static const std::string ora = "orange";
  static const std::string ba = "banana";

    switch(type)
    {
    case 0:
        return ap;
    case 1:
        return ora;
    case 2:
        return ba;
    }
    
    return {};
}

static void static_return_ref_string(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int> v(10000);
    std::iota(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 0);

  for (auto _ : state) {
   for (const auto &n : v) {
        const auto& ignore = return_static_ref_string(n % 3);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ignore);        
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(static_return_ref_string);
```

Comment: Did you do your measurements with -O3 option? Also, you can significantly increase perfomance of `return_static_string()` if you will return const reference to sting instead of copy,, but you will need to use static variable for empty string as well.

Comment: You can follow the link on quick benchmark page https://godbolt.org/z/WYY5s7sdj and compare assemblers. The second one always makes string copies. The first one is optimized somehow.

Comment: @sklott, yes. I chose optim = O3 from the interface.

Comment: external links can break, please try to include all necessary information in the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I have included all codes within the OP. thank you

Comment: @sklott, your idea is right on spot. I should have used `const std::string&` and `const auto&`. After making the changes, now performance benchmark matches my expectation.

https://quick-bench.com/q/ySkIgg7MFRWFqZTi8HJNjr9UVKo

Comment: @273K Probably SSO (constructing the returned string at the call site).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this comes to the allocation & reallocation code generated by the compiler.
Strings literals are stored in the `.DATA` section of the executable, while returning copies of a static `std::string` object causes the allocation of heap memory for those strings.

The generated code for `return_string` function (literal strings) is almost 40% shorter than what `return_static_string` (static string objects copies) in *Compiler Explorer*

The code I tested was:

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

constexpr std::size_t kBenchmarkLength{1024};
constexpr bool kLiteralBenchmark = true;

template <bool Literal>
std::string return_string(int type)
{
    if constexpr (Literal)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
        case 0:
            return "apple";
        case 1:
            return "orange";
        case 2:
            return "banana";
        }
    } else {
        static const std::string ap = "apple";
        static const std::string ora = "orange";
        static const std::string ba = "banana";

        switch(type)
        {
        case 0:
            return ap;
        case 1:
            return ora;
        case 2:
            return ba;
        }
    
    }

    return {};
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec(kBenchmarkLength);

    for (std::size_t i{0}; i < kBenchmarkLength; ++i) {
        auto str =  return_string<kLiteralBenchmark>(i % 3);
        vec.push_back(str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The results with `gcc 12.2` were:

- For literal strings: *143* lines with `-Ofast`, and *93* lines with `-Os`
- For static copies: *275* lines with `-Ofast`, and *190* lines with `-Os`